# PHP Sessions to keep track of user type

Tags: php, session, authentication

I'm currently using sessions to keep track of the user type on my website. I only have admin, user, and not logged in all associated with an integer. So, for example, `$_SESSION['user_type'] = 1` then I know the person logged on is an administrator.

I was wondering if it is necessary, or good practice at least, to hash anything like this and then check against the hash so that users are not able to easily manipulate any variables.

This isn't a big concern of mine, but seeing that this is my first website, I'd like to start getting in the practice of doing what I should. Also, if this is just not the most efficient way to do this, I'd love suggestions. This is just the only way I thought of to do this.

Thanks,
Sabrina

Comment: Sessions are generated serverside and is unique to the user, so there's no need to hash it. If anything, you may end up doing more harm than good.

Comment: _“so that users are not able to easily manipulate any variables”_ – all session _data_ is kept on the server, so the only manipulation can happen through (your) code. So the only problem in that regard could be if users were able to call code parts that they are not supposed to, f.e. via an HTTP request.

Comment: @Fred what about session hijacking and session fixation...?

Comment: That's another ball of twine @webeno Edit: Which I've rectified.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Fred! I had read there was some possibility, but with my use here, I think that is exactly what I was looking for in an answer!

Comment: As Webeno pointed out, read up on session hijacking and session fixation => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking @user3590702 and => https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation